# Memcached Eviction Rate Performance

Tags: memcached, dynatrace

We are monitoring Memcached servers using the Dynatrace tool, the Memcached is mainly used to store user sessions related data.

- Number of Memcached Servers: 3
- Memory Assigned to each instance: 2 GB

We have recently increased the Memcached memory (from 1 GB to 2 GB) when we had user sessions related issues where users could not Sign In.

We thus increased the Memcached memory for 1 GB to 2 GB.
Post increasing we observed a decrease in Eviction rate in the Monitoring tool (Dynatrace)

(There were NO other server/JVM related issues)

My Question:
Can I co-relate the User sessions with the Eviction rate?
Are there any other parameter/metric that I should look in for Memcached?
Is the eviction rate normal 200/s to 400/s normal?

Here is the snap of the Eviction rate and Max bytes for last 72 hours
[Eviction Rate and Max_bytes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1tmqp.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

When Dynatrace detects a problem with your user sessions it will also automatically check for anomalies in related metrics.

It is impossible to give a general recommendation on a "good" eviction rate. Focus on the user sessions and the user experience. As long as user experience is OK i wouldn't care about the eviction rate. If you should see problems with user sessions and Dynatrace should also report a relation to anomalies of the eviction rate metric, i can recommend you [this article](https://medium.com/@ivaramme/memcached-and-unexpected-evictions-a3a50a239108). It explains an interesting relation between the size of objects that are stored in memcached and unexpected evictions.